# Windows 10 universal app UserControl in stackpanel

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-10-universal

I need to place a custom UserControl into a Stackpannel.
I have this UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ScannerApp.Custom_Controls.LocationAndQuantity"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScannerApp.Custom_Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="20"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="Red" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143">
            <TextBlock x:Name="locationTxt" Text="location" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock x:Name="quantityTxt" Text="quantity" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and a page with stackpanel

```
<Page
    x:Class="ScannerApp.FindPN___STEP2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScannerApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        ...
        <StackPanel>
            <!--here I want to place the userControls-->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I tried some sollutions like `<controls: ...> //this could not be found by intellisense even` or

```
<my:UserControlName Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ... />
<Window ... 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:AssemblyName"
    ...
/>
```

but I don't have the Window here... I tried to place something similar into the Page, but I don't really know what to type in there.

Comment: you need to add a namespace to your usercontrol so put a new namespace right under `xmlns:mc="http[...]` like `xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:MyAppNamespace;"` after that you can use your control like `<myControls:ControlName />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you've to fix your XAML. If you want to use custom controls you've to tell the compiler where the controls come from.

In case you Controls namespace is

> ScannerApp.Custom_Controls

You've to write the Page XAML as

```
<Page
    x:Class="ScannerApp.FindPN___STEP2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScannerApp.Custom_Controls" <!--FIXED HERE-->
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    ...
    <StackPanel>
      <local:NameOfYourControl x:Name="MyNewControl" /> <!--Properties can be added-->
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```